# Treeview - SelectedNodeChanged not working for appended hyperlink

Tags: asp.net

In the following code

```
 <asp:TreeNode Text="node text here <a>Click</a>" Value="1" Expanded="False">
   <asp:TreeNode Text="er" Value="0"></asp:TreeNode>                              
   <asp:TreeNode Text="err" Value="1"></asp:TreeNode>
   <asp:TreeNode Text="err" Value="2"></asp:TreeNode>
 </asp:TreeNode>
```

I have custom code in the 'SelectedNodeChanged' event. This event is triggered when I click on the node text ("node text here") but not triggered when I click on the hyperlink (anchor tag "Click"). How can I make the anchor  tag click also to behave like 'selectednodechanged'.

Comment: you need to provide the code ..

Comment: why you want to add <a> tag ?

Comment: @Muhammad Akhtar : That is a requirement of my project. I need node text in the treeview control and a hyperlink next to each node text. Right now even though the node text and the <a tag hyper link are on the same line, click on hyperlink does not trigger 'selectednodechanged' event... I have to explicitly click on the node text to trigger that.

Comment: @Akram Shahda - Thanks for taking a look.Thats pretty what much I have at this moment. the end </asp:treenode> is missing as the fifth line of code above....I have a couple of lines to test code in the selectednodechanged event but that is irrelevant..

Comment: Made edits to the code.. please note.

Answer (score 1):

Clicking on the item and causing a postback when selecting the node should happen because a `__doPostBack` fires on the node; because the hyperlink handles its own click, you could try also handle a click event for the link, and than manually invoke a `__doPostBack` yourself.  Take a look at the rendered markup and look for any existing `__doPostBack` statements, and you'd have to emulate that.

HTH.

Comment: Do you mean like this..<a onClick="Somefunction();"> and then in javascript, write _doPostBack for that function. Is that the idea? can you elaborate if you can.. thank you

Comment: Yes, or <a onclick="__doPostBack('<control ID>', '<command>');">Content</a>.  The issue is, the control ID/command combo is a unique combo that you would have to make sure you pass the right values, which is why you have to examine the content...

Comment: Error 4 System.Web.UI.WebControls.TreeNodeCollection must have items of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.TreeNode'. 'a' is of type 'System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlAnchor' -- When I looked up source and added the two parameters for ControlId and Command. Am I missing anything?

Comment: In the HTML?  If HTML, you shouldn't get a server-side error like this... It seems like its interpreting <a> as a server control.  Do you have runat="server" defined?  That must not be set...

Comment: But the <a> tag is appended inside the text property of a TreeView control... there is no runat="server" defined anywhere. Here is the code I have so far. <asp:TreeNode Text="Text here <a onClick="__doPostBack('ctl00$MainContent$TabContainer1$TabPanel3$TreeView1&#39', 'sImgSfrt&#39');">Add</a>" Value="imgsf" Expanded="False">
                                <asp:TreeNode Text="asdasd" Value="0"></asp:TreeNode>
                            </asp:TreeNode>

Comment: It is actually a Build Error.. when I run it, I get the Build error.

Comment: Oh, OK.. for some reason, it's interpreting the <a> as a control, which I didn't think it should.  It may not then be possible to do this...

Comment: how about writing javascript for onclick event. That seems to trigger the code. How would you emulate a tree nodes 'selectednodechanged' event via <a tag's onclick javascript. Any ideas?

Comment: No, you'd have to inspect the markup... and see what the markup does.  That's what I meant earlier, for onclick or href, use the __doPostBack method.  Actually, you mentioned a build error above, but you have the onclick defined there, so that's not what actually is causing the build error?

Comment: If I write just plain onclick=function() , then it runs the javascript function without any problems..but if I replace onclick =_dopostback... then I get the build error.

Comment: Why that would happen is beyond me, other than maybe it's capturing the tag that fires the method and that's why... but I don't think that's it.